# How to let combobox open when lost focus

Tags: wpf, combobox

I try to let my combobox open when i go on an other control.
I implement a virtual keyboard in my application and when i click on KeyButton, my combobox is closed. It's the problem.I want to play with my keyboard with my combobox open?
Is it possible? Maybe an hack exist?

Regards,
Matthieu

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to do anything with your combobox events. Just open its dropdown on KeyButton click like this:

```
ComboBoxName.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

it worked for a simple test so if you have something more complicated - please specify all conditions